# Unable to delete project from UI in sonarqube 4.5.7 running on BigIP

Tags: sonarqube-4.5

I have a running instance of sonar 4.5.7 and have recently moved it on https by utilizing the BigIP platform.
Rule has been written in BigIP that even if some user access the sonar URL on http they will be redirected to https.

As of now the things are working fine however noticed one anomaly.Request you to kindly guide on that.

Being an admin I tried to delete a sample project using Project Configuration-->Deletion (on top right hand side of dashboard) but strangely I was not able to accomplish it. The page now shows as "You are being redirected"
The project still remains.Below is response in chrome browser :

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.us.com/sonar/project/deletion/771057' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://test.us.com/sonar/project'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Can I overcome this challenge ? I tried tweaking deletion.html.erb and _delete_form.html.erb files inside web folder of sonarqube server but no luck.

P.S:
The rest api's are working perfectly fine over https link.

Answer (score 0):

As of now was able to make this flow work by tweaking the SSL variable defined in below file web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/request.rb However don't know the repercussions hence decided to live with the problem.